# ggMap with Time Series Scale in R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap, googlevis, timeserieschart

Updated:

First attempt at a question on stack so apologies if I don't meet proper conventions first go round. I'm wanting to see if anyone has created a plot using ggMap that applies a time series scale to data. My goal is to show how 'conversions' change over time in different cities. For example, my data frame would contain the following:

```
head(testdata)
 Date       city Total.Conversions      lat      long    newdate
1 5/12/15    Brandon                 1 43.81037 -73.09998 2015-05-12
2 5/12/15 Carrollton                 1 36.94063 -76.53780 2015-05-12
3 5/12/15    Chicago                 1 41.85000 -87.65000 2015-05-12
4 5/12/15    Concord                 2 42.45720 -71.37478 2015-05-12
5 5/12/15    El Paso                 1 40.73166 -89.03978 2015-05-12
6 5/12/15  Fairfield                 1 44.60333 -69.63627 2015-05-12
```

My goal is to create an interactive map with something like googleVis in order to scale conversions by day by city. Below is the code I am using to create the map:

```
map <- get_map(location=c(lon = -98.35, lat = 39.50), zoom = 4, source="google",maptype="roadmap",crop=FALSE)
ggmap(map)
ggmap(map)+geom_point(aes(x = testdata$long, y = testdata$lat), data = testdata, alpha = .1, color = "darkgreen", size = sqrt(testdata$Total.Conversions)/2)
```

The map output is as such:

[image: ggmap]

But ideally I'd like a slider underneath that would allow me to adjust a `testdata$newdate`, and in turn show `testdata$Total.Conversions` accumulatively by day.

If anyone can offer any solutions to this it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Why did you try so far? We don't provide ready-to-use script.

Comment: Why can't you post an image?

Comment: @jlhoward Likely because embedding images is not possible if you don't have enough rep. Could try a link, though.

Comment: @sebastian-c Right, but the limit is 10. Stu - try again to post an image.

Comment: Hey guys. Updated the original post to provide a better understanding of what I'm looking to do. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that you want to consider using shiny for this.

Comment: @jazzurro - this is probably what I'd need so I'll have a further look into it. Thanks for pointing out though.